# Can a grunt task run other grunt tasks?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, multitasking

So I mean something like:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['default']); // CLI: grunt
grunt.registerTask('serve', ['serve']); // CLI: grunt serve
grunt.registerTask('test', ['test']); // CLI: grunt test
```

And then I want just one task which runs the 3 of those in one call, like, if I type into the cmd "grunt tasks", it runs any tasks I want such as default, serve or test in the order I specify, etc.

Can this be done? The docs arent very clear (maybe its my dyspraxia, but it just doesnt read well to me).

Cheers,

-- SD

Comment: [registerTask](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks) takes a taskList as parameter if that's you want to know (the arrays you have)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can very easily.

From the documentation:

> You can configure Grunt to run one or more tasks by default by
>   defining a default task. 
>   In the following example, running grunt at the command line without specifying a task will run the uglify task.
>   This is functionally the same as explicitly running grunt uglify or even grunt default. **Any number of tasks (with or without arguments) may be specified in the array.**

The key part of the excerpt above is bolded.

For example, create a task called `runAllThree`, and specify all three tasks you'd like to run inside of the array.

`grunt.registerTask('runAllThree', ['default', 'serve', 'test']);`

Comment: See, that is much clearer, thanks! WIll try this when I get back to the house in half an hour!

Comment: Glad I can help @SkullDev .  Read up on "Alias Tasks" here http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks